# How to show start - destination screen with the address on map

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am working on application where I have to show start - destination screen of map.I want to show the direction with my current address to the destination.I am having destination address as string and not latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
Intent intent = new 
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="destination address text"));
    startActivity(intent);
```